# Starting second controller after first controller has finished its task in a single thread group

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-4.0

[image]

I have a structure where in I have multiple controllers in a thread group. Second controller is depended on first. Controller 1 and 2 csv file will have multiple records.

I have divided the tasks in multiple user threads.
As of now, I am enabling first then executing the tasks. Then once the first is done, I am disabling that and enabling teh second one and starting. 
Is there a way where we can say that the second will only run once first has completed the operation?? Does Jmeter allow this type of execution ?

Answer (score 1):

JMeter executes test elements upside down so you don't have to do anything

[image]

If you want **all virtual users** to execute Controller 1 and only then start executing Controller 2 add [Synchronizing Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeter-synchronizing-timer) as a child of the last Sampler of the Controller 1 and set `Number of Simultaneous Users to Group by` to be equal to the number of Threads in your [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group)

[image]